# How to remove Comma from output element after mapping an Array in React js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want the output like: Custom(F,T,S)

But output comes like,

[image]

My code:

'Custom' + `(${data.state?.days?.map((item) => item.day ? item.day : '')})`

Thanks...........

Comment: Use `Array.filter()` to remove items with empty `day`, and then map the filtered array to extract the days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL&DR :

```
'Custom' + (${data.state?.days?.filter((item) => !!item.day).map((item) => item.day)})
```

`Array.map` always transform all the entries of an array.
In your case, you have some some item that don't have a "day".
So, you create a new array with empty elements

First, you have to filter your array :

```
data.state?.days?.filter((item) => !!item.day)
```

Then map through it

```
data.state?.days?.filter((item) => !!item.day).map((item) => item.day)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have items without day, so filter them out:

```
[{day: 'M'}, {day: 'T'}, {day: 'W'}, {noday: 'T'}, {day: 'F'}].map((item) => item.day ? item.day : '').filter(s => s.length > 0)
```